# Como passar uma variavel de paramento de url em web api que contenha / ou um ponto de interrogação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Estou a desenvolver uma api em .net core e reparei que no url se eu quiser passar por exemplo
https://localhost:44365/api/values/test=?/
ou
https://localhost:44365/api/values/test=//

Ocorre um erro

```
[HttpGet("test={test}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(string test)
{
  return  test;
}
```

[Actualização em relação à resposta postada por @LINQ]

Com `%3F`já funciona
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já assim ainda não funciona
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034227/how-to-match-web-api-2-route-with-forward-slashes-in-request-parameters Eu tentei algo assim mas tambem nao de

Comment: https://imgur.com/6amNLXC

Answer (score 2):

`?` e `/` são caracteres reservados numa URL.

Você vai precisar encodar esses caracteres:

**`?`** fica **`%3F`** e **`/`** fica **`%2F`**.

Note que, se seu parâmetro deveria ser na query string, você está definindo a rota de forma errada.

Você deveria usar o atributo `[FromRoute]`. Assim:

```
[HttpGet("{test}")]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] string test)
{
    return Ok(test);
}
```

Comment: %2F nao funciona mas o %3F funcionou

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Aí é como você está testando que tem algum problema. Acabei de testar pelo Postman e funciona como esperado.

Comment: Como eu disse, o problema é outro. https://imgur.com/a/lS0nw3g

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034227/how-to-match-web-api-2-route-with-forward-slashes-in-request-parameters Eu tentei algo assim mas tambem nao deu

Comment: https://imgur.com/6amNLXC

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes esse parâmetro deveria ser uma querystring. Certo?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Veja a minha edição.

Comment: actualizei no codigo mas nao funcionoi na mesma será que tenho de fazer alguma configuração nas rotas?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107198/discussion-between-amadeu-antunes-and-linq).

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Certifique-se que de o teste está certo.

Comment: fiz igual e ainda não foi desta